# How to stop continual launching of app?

Tags: git, merge, application-launch, difftool

I'm using Tower for Git.  On a commit, I clicked "Difftool".  This launches my merge program (P4Merge).  It launches it for every file that needs to be diffed, one at a time.  So every time I close P4Merge, the next diff is opened.  Tried quitting Tower, no luck.  There's hundreds of files.  I have to reboot to stop it.

How can I prevent an app from opening continually, or erase the queue that is launching it?

Comment: If you used the console, you could simply press CTRL-C thus breaking the difftool loop.

Comment: Nope, Tower initiated the launches.